# How to write extracted email headers in a new email

Tags: office-js

I'm trying to develop an Outlook Add-In that allows to extract headers from a selected email and print them in a new email.

For that need, I used the following method to create a new email that includes, as an attachment, the selected email:

```
Office.context.mailbox.displayNewMessageForm({
    toRecipients: ["firstname.name@email.com"],
    subject: mailSubject,
    htmlBody: mailBody,
    attachments: [{ type: "item", itemId: Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId, name: Office.context.mailbox.item.subject }]
});
```

I looked at the following method to get the headers from the selected email:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.getAllInternetHeadersAsync(
    function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
            headers = asyncResult.value; // get the headers
        }
    }
);
```

(Un)fortunately, this method is asynchronous and I get the headers after the creation of the new email (displayNewMessageForm). My goal is to write these headers in the parameter **htmlBody** used for the creation of the new email.

I tried to used the async method for the email creation (displayNewMessageFormAsync), without success.
If possible, I want to get the headers (asynchronously) and pass them as a parameter of the displayNewMessageForm() method or update the created email to add the headers (if possible again).

I'm looking for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`displayNewMessageForm` should be used in the callback handler of `getAllInternetHeadersAsync`.

This works for us:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.getAllInternetHeadersAsync(
    function(asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
            headers = asyncResult.value; // get the headers
            Office.context.mailbox.displayNewMessageForm({
                toRecipients: ["firstname.name@email.com"],
                subject: "Test Subject",
                htmlBody: "Internet headers: " + headers,
                attachments: [{
                    type: "item",
                    itemId: Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId,
                    name: Office.context.mailbox.item.subject
                }]
            });
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer but it seems to not work on my side...

I added console.log() methods to check what it executed and when : it enters in the displayNewMessageForm() method but executes nothing (I don't see the mail).